# Sets that have a product of 10010

Tags: combinatorics

Let F be the set of unique factorizations of the number 10 010. More precisely, a unique
factorization is an unordered multiset (an element can appear more than once) of integers
greater than 1 such that the product of all its elements is 10 010, for example {10, 1001} could
be one such element of F. Note that by this definition, {1001, 10} is equivalent to {10, 1001}.
How many elements are there in F?

My try:

I split it into 5 cases, based on the number of elements.

since
$$10010 = 2*5*7*11*13$$
if we split into into 1 product, then $5C5 = 1$

then if we split it into 2 products, the we would get $5C1 + 5C2 = 15$

if we split into 3 products, since $5 = 1+3+1 ; 2+2+1$ then we would get $5C3 * 2C1/2 + 5C2*3C2/2 = 10 + 15 = 25 $

if we split into 4 products, since 5 = 1+1+1+2, then $5C2*3C1*2C1*1C1/3! = 10 $

if we split into 5 products, since 5= 1+1+1+1+1, then $5C1*4C1*3C1*2C1*1C1/5! = 1$

which is only 52, the answer is 54, what could I have not counted? Is the counting above correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your counting is correct. The answer is $52$.

In fact, this is the fifth term ($B_5$) of the sequence [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) ([A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110) in OEIS).